# Modify a target installation path

Tags: cmake, installation

I have a override the basic `add_library` to add more logic, and also sets a default installation path using `install`.

```
    install(TARGETS ${TARGET}
        RUNTIME
            DESTINATION bin
        LIBRARY
            DESTINATION bin
        ARCHIVE
            DESTINATION bin
    )
```

But on some cases, I want the installation path to be somewhere else, so I call `install` with the new path. When I execute the `install` target from the cmake command line, it puts the binary produce in ***both*** places.

```
    install(TARGETS MyLibrary
        RUNTIME
            DESTINATION lib
        LIBRARY
            DESTINATION lib
        ARCHIVE
            DESTINATION lib
    )
```

Is there a way to modify the install destination of a target, or overwrite it?

Comment: The [`install()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html) command has many signatures. Can you provide some examples showing **exactly which** install commands you are using?

Comment: @squareskittles I edited the post. I am using `install(TARGETS)`.